# how can I aggregate kafka topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

i need to carry market data from source to target. i'd like to put each symbol , ie. BTCUSD in its own topic and have the target app subscribe to as many topics as it wants and receive data of multiple symbols in correct time based order.

i am currently putting all data into a single topic , and have the target filter out the data it's not interested in.

can i achieve what i want with kafka alone , or with an additional project , or can you name another message broker for the job.

thanks.

Comment: You say you put symbols in their own topics, but then you say you put all data in one topic... Which is it? And consumers can subscribe to as many topics as they want (I wouldn't call this aggregation, though, as that means something specific in _Kafka Streams_). Ultimately, filtering anything on the consumer side will only cause lag and overhead

Comment: I think we'd need more details about what your app is doing to give a good recommendation. Like OneCricket said you don't want to filter 99% of your data but one topic per stock ticker could be a bit much.

Also 

> receive data of multiple symbols in correct time based order

keeping the processing in time based order can be tricky, depending on if you mean the time the data is produced or if the data itself has a timestamp. You may need to introduce kafka streams or something custom to enforce that ordering